# how to automatically scroll down in my page?

Tags: autoscroll

Is there a code for automatic scrolling on the page?
It looks like an automatic scroll button on this page:
https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/shania_twain/youre_still_the_one_chords_1345

And the user can determine the speed of the scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If you have an option to use javascript you may use this,

https://codepen.io/michaelvinci/pen/qKVBLG?page=1&
```

Comment: Hi thanks. This code is only for a Div with a fixed height. How can I use this code to scroll the whole page at different heights?

Comment: While link only answers may help the OP at the time, it may not help in the future due to links becoming dead if the page is removed or overwritten. Please consider adding the relevant code to your answer alongside the link as reference.